# lubuntu - Live USB Installation Keeps Warning "No Space Left on Device" But Swap, RAM, and Data Partition Have Space

Tags: live-usb, live-cd, memory-usage, storage, memory-leak

I installed lubuntu on a flash drive along side a few other distros using [ventoy](https://www.ventoy.net/en/index.html), there is also a ~10GB partition for data. But it seems the storage space is shrinking. Its a new drive, 64 gigs, but it seems every boot I am able to store less and less files and install less software.

The swap partition was almost full on my last boot so I thought it might be that or if something did not get erased a couple times when there was a hard shut down (battery died, hit power button when in sleep mode because I thought it may have shut off, etc.), but now firefox keeps crashing and swap/RAM don't seem anywhere near full.

Sometimes it seems that even very small files (not always) take a long time to copy.

Im using live boot because I have been borrowing a computer.

I did install quite a bit of software before and I am wondering if data is getting stored somewhere and is not registering. Besides that, I hope I am not killing the drive. I know they have a limited life time, but I have only been using it for less than a week.

Anyone have any idea why I cant seem to utilize the full memory? Or where files may be getting stored without the ability to see them?

Thanks!

UPDATE:
Strange thing just happened, I tried to copy a document to the data partition, it would not let me do it to folder A but would let me do it to folder B, I tried de-fragmenting it (with `e4defrag`), but it would not let my copy a different file over.

Comment: Your mention of `ventoy` implies to me you've not installed the system at all, but are you using *live* which is not the same thing (even *live* when used with persistence is not an installed system without the benefits of an installed system). You're without details (what release?) and its unclear, but I don't see how *defrag* would help with a COW type system (ie. when the system is used *live*, new data doesn't overwrite the old; it's COPY ON WRITE or COW as its only intended to 'try' prior to installing properly).

Comment: @guiverc Yes, it is live. There is no persistence except for the data in the data partition of the USB drive which is why I find this strange. You mentioned COW though, never heard of that before this, could that have something to do with the missing space? Perhaps because it is in an unusual configuration, booted with ventoy?

Comment: A *live* system is run from RAM, and a *virtual* file-system is created in RAM that gets used. If you make changes, install upgrades; as there is no installed system (yet), and changes to the ISO cannot be made (it's RO) a COPY ON WRITE method is used meaning additional copies get created in the *created at boot* file-system in RAM.  If you change too much, the system in RAM will become full, and a reboot is required so it can be created fresh. You can do a huge amount on a *live* system, but you cannot use it as if it's installed as it's not by design, and the *fs* created at boot will fill.

Comment: @guiverc I understand its a RAM disk (also using swap memeory), however `htop` shows that RAM has plenty of space when I keep getting "No space left on device" errors. Something seems to be affecting it across boot cycles, either that or the order in which I do things is some how effecting storage.

There might be some sort of fragmented memory (given what happened in UPDATE)